# string.split is not working for some reason

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I am trying to print the last name of the person "Michael" by splitting the string into an array and calling out the next word available.

When I run this code, I get undefined. I tried using Pythontutor to see what am I doing wrong and it turns out that `string.split()` is not working.

Can you please take a look and help figure me out what am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```js
function getMichaelLastName(inputText) {
  var names = inputText;
  var newN = [names.split(" ")]; 
  for (var i = 0; i<newN.length; i++) {
    if(newN[i] == "Michael") {
      var Michael = newN[i++];
    }
    return Michael;
  }
}
console.log(
getMichaelLastName("Michael, how are you? - Cool, how is John Williamns and Michael Jordan? I don't know but Michael Johnson is fine. Michael do you still score points with LeBron James, Michael Green AKA Star and Michael Wood?")
)
```

Comment: It's because if you slit at `' '` The  Michael part won't be Michael it will be `Michael,`

Comment: newN is a 1-element array containing an array of strings. you also return in the first loop iteration each time, regardless of conditional outcome.

Comment: It returns undefined. I will try to fix the other errors once this one is fixed. Can your run it on your console?

Comment: @dandavis can you please tell me how do i fix it?

Comment: Don't put `[]` around `names.split(" ")`. `split()` returns an array, you don't need to put it in another array.

Comment: `let getMichaelLastName = x=>x.split("Michael ").pop().split(" ")[0];`

Comment: a RegEx would be a better solution to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular Expression.  Search for word boundaries and Michael followed by Alphabetic word.

interactive RegEx demo with explanations here: https://regex101.com/r/gC8tsi/2
`/\bMichael ([A-Z][a-z]*?)\b/g` is a regular expression literal (syntax is enclosed by`/` to indicate a regular expression). Regular expressions are a pattern syntax designed for processing text with patterns.
`\b` looks for word boundaries.  Basically boundaries where it finds non-word elements.
`Michael_` just looks for that string.
`[A-Z]` looks for a uppercase letter
`[a-z]*?` is a lazy sequence of lowercase letters (matches until the next word boundary `\b`)

The map and slice at the end is just to slice off the first name from all found names.
`||[]` just returns an empty array for the case where no matches are found.

```js
function getMichaelLastName(inputText) {
  return (inputText.match(/\bMichael ([A-Z][a-z]*?)\b/g)||[]).map(x=>x.slice('Michael '.length))
}
console.log(
getMichaelLastName("Michael, how are you? - Cool, how is John Williamns and Michael Jordan? I don't know but Michael Johnson is fine. Michael do you still score points with LeBron James, Michael Green AKA Star and Michael Wood?")
)

function getLastNames(inputText, name='Michael') {
  const rex = new RegExp(String.raw`\b${name} ([A-Z][a-z]*?)\b`,'g')
  return (inputText.match(rex)||[]).map(x=>x.slice(name.length+1))
}
console.log(
getLastNames("Michael, how are you? - Cool, how is John Williamns and Michael Jordan? I don't know but Michael Johnson is fine. Michael do you still score points with LeBron James, Michael Green AKA Star and Michael Wood?",'John'),
getLastNames("Michael, how are you? - Cool, how is John Williamns and Michael Jordan? I don't know but Michael Johnson is fine. Michael do you still score points with LeBron James, Michael Green AKA Star and Michael Wood?",'Michael')
)
```

Comment: Hi, Your code is accurate and return what I want. Can you please explain how it works?

Comment: interactive demo with details explanations here: https://regex101.com/r/gC8tsi/2

Comment: This website is superhelpful. I still have some doubts. Please correct me if i am wrong. /\bMichael ([A-Z][a-z]*?\b looks for the word Michael in the string. g is for global scope. ```*?``` is to limit the number of searches. ```||[]``` pushes it into an empty array. Now I dont understand this ES6 part. I think it is mapping the string. But why do we need map. Can't we just use Push?

Comment: No `||[]` doesn't push to an empty array.  It returns an empty array if match is falsey (or null in this case).  This avoids `(null).map` is not a function.  `*?` isn't actually necessary, and `*` would have worked.  The return value of `.match` is already an array.  It's just going through all the strings in the array and cutting off the first name.  `.map` as a one-pass comprehension is just more concise than creating a for loop to push to a new array.

Comment: Oh right. I get it. Can you please explain the next part as well? I am still midway learning JS. Sorry if I sound stupid

Comment: Do you mean the second function that works for arbitrary names?  It's using the RegExp constructor to compile a regular expression with the name inserted at ${name} using template string syntax, since I can't do that with the regex literal which doesn't allow constructing an arbitrary regex at runtime.  `String.raw` is a new template string function that allows processing raw strings, so I don't have to escape the `\\`.

Comment: Oh, now i get it. I have learn more about the Regex function though. Thanks a lot for your helpful insight and answer. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

Your code has multiple issues:

- Don't use `newN[i++]` because you're updating the `i` value. Use `newN[i+1]` instead;
- You've got some scopes issues. You can learn more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope
- If the last word of the sentence was 'Michael', you'll get a overflow error (`newN[i+1]` does not exist).
- The `split` function already returns an array.

```js
function getMichaelLastName(inputText) {
  var names = inputText;
  var newN = names.split(" ");
  var michaelLastnames = []
  
  for (var i = 0; i<newN.length - 1; i++) {
    if(newN[i] == "Michael") {
      michaelLastnames.push(newN[i+1]);
    }
  }
  
  return michaelLastnames;
}

var michaelLastname = getMichaelLastName("Michael, how are you? - Cool, how is John Williamns and Michael Jordan? I don't know but Michael Johnson is fine. Michael do you still score points with LeBron James, Michael Green AKA Star and Michael Wood?")

console.log(michaelLastname)
```

Comment: Maby make `michaelLastname` an `array` and `.push()` all the names into the `array`. It's just an idea for @bitch_ctrl

Comment: 1. michaelLastName declares it as a global scope i guess.
2. I think i was aware of newN[i++] but i still used it. I dont know why.
3. I have some confusion with return types. Can you share a guide or something which helps me with the return type functions?

thanks a lot for your answer. It helps a lot

Comment: return _exits the function_ and returns a value.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return  what you're attempting to do is more like `.map`.  split already returns array.  [blah.split()] would wrap the result in an array and give you [ [split1, split2, split3] ]  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split  just look up the functions on Google to find out what they return

Answer (score 1):

return words after Michael

```
function getMichaelLastName(inputText) {
  let newArr = []
  var names = inputText;
  var newN = names.split(" "); 
  for (var i = 0; i<newN.length; i++) {
    if(newN[i] === "Michael") {
      newArr = [...newArr, newN[i + 1]]
    }
  }
  return newArr
}
```

if you want return last name:

```
function getMichaelLastName(inputText) {
  let newArr = ''
  var names = inputText;
  var newN = names.split(" "); 
  for (var i = 0; i<newN.length; i++) {
    if(newN[i] === "Michael") {
      newArr = newN[i + 1]
    }
  }
  return newArr
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code uses regex and capture the word (ie, potential lastname) after `Michael<space>`

```js
const regex = /Michael (\w+)/gm;
const str = "Michael, how are you? - Cool, how is John Williamns and Michael Jordan? I don't know but Michael Johnson is fine. Michael do you still score points with LeBron James, Michael Green AKA Star and Michael Wood?";
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }

    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getMichaelLastName(inputText) {
    var Michaels = [];
    var names = inputText;
    var newN = names.split(' ');
    for (var i = 0; i < newN.length; i++) {
        const x = newN[i];
        if (x.includes( "Michael")) {
            if(newN[i+1].length>3)
                Michaels.push(newN[i + 1].replace('?',''));
        }

    }
    return Michaels;
}
console.log(
getMichaelLastName("Michael, how are you? - Cool, how is John Williamns and Michael Jordan? I don't know but Michael Johnson is fine. Michael do you still score points with LeBron James, Michael Green AKA Star and Michael Wood?")
)
```